# Object deserializes xml just fine, but not json

Tags: .net, serialization, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I found this to be a very odd problem. When I send in an xml request to my web api service, every deserializes just fine. However, when I send in a json request, this ONE property will not deserialize. Here are the objects:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class TransactionData
{
    // bunch of other properties that are unaffected ...

    private GeotagInfo _geotag;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "GeotagInfo", Order = 7)]
    public GeotagInfo GeotagInfo
    {
        get { return _geotag ?? new GeotagInfo(); }
        set { _geotag = value; }
    }
}


[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class GeotagInfo
{

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "Longitude", Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "Latitude", Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    [Image(Nullable = true)]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "MapImage", Order = 3, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string MapImage { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
}
```

When break at the entrypoint in the controller with the xml request. The geotag property is there and full populated. When I do the same with the json request, the geotag property is instantiated but all of its values are null. Everything else in this parent object are fine.

This is the property in the json request:

```
"GeotagInfo": {
  "Longitude": "-yy.yyyy",
  "Latitude": "xx.xxxx",
  "MapImage": "base64 string"
}
```

Notice the property getter `get { return _geotag ?? new GeotagInfo(); }`

The xml request doesn't have a problem with this. But if I remove it and make it `get { return _geotag; }` then the problem goes away. Unfortunately this causes other problems deeper into the service.

What's going on here? How does it work fine with xml but not json (unless i remove the default getter). I know that MVC4 uses json.net, so that may have something to do with it.

NOTE: As suggested in other threads, I have tried removing the serializable attributes from the classes. No change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently, there is definitely a difference in the order of operations with the Json.net serializer. I wonder if it's attempting to do some sort of lazy deserialize for performance. At any rate, there was a bug that I wrote which revealed the difference in serializers:

```
get { return _geotag ?? new GeotagInfo(); }
```

This never sets the private field. It should be:

```
get { return _geotag ?? (_geotag = new GeotagInfo()); }
```

So my assumption is that the private field never got set, which is what makes me feel like it is set up to inherently lazy load deserialize. So now that we're past the deserialization process, the check that is being performed on the private field will always return null, thus defaulting to returning an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to create two properties, one for the serialization, and another for further use:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class TransactionData
{
    // bunch of other properties that are unaffected ...

    private GeotagInfo _geotag;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "GeotagInfo", Order = 7)]
    public DataMember_GeotagInfo GeotagInfo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public GeotagInfo GeotagInfo
    {
        get { return DataMember_GeotagInfo ?? new GeotagInfo(); }
        set { DataMember_GeotagInfo = value; }
    }
}
```